# Union tools for polyline in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, union, line-on-line-overlay

I'm trying to combine 2 polylines into one with all features and their attributes will be written to the output feature class.

I'm trying to use the Union tools but it won't work on polyline, any help?

The only solution I've had in mind is to buffer these 2 polylines and then run the union tools.

Comment: Two polylines or two polyline feature classes? If you are trying to combine feature classes a spatial join should work https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000016000000 available with all license levels, if you are trying to erase an overlapping line Planarize Lines from the Advanced Editing toolbar should work https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m800000012000000

Comment: Thank you so much, it works with spatial join, I just need to change the match option to IDENTICAL. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?